# Why can't I see my new partition in the file system

Tags: partitioning

I ran GParted from the 'LiveCD' Shrank the large partition, created a new one, and saved the changes, but now running Ubuntu I can't see this partition.

What is my failing? Apologies if it's a bit of a basic mistake...

```
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  262GB  262GB   primary   ext4            boot
 3      262GB   496GB  234GB   primary   ext2
 2      496GB   500GB  4170MB  extended
 5      496GB   500GB  4170MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: did you try to create new partition and install ubuntu on it?

Comment: upload the gparted screenshot to imgur.com ,i will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Where did you expect to see it? Did you create a file system on the new partition? You could also edit your question to show us the output of `sudo parted -l` or a screenshot of gparted.

Comment: No Avinash. I installed Ubuntu, then after created the new partition.  Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  262GB  262GB   primary   ext4            boot
 3      262GB   496GB  234GB   primary   ext2
 2      496GB   500GB  4170MB  extended
 5      496GB   500GB  4170MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)

Comment: You need to do put @AvinashRaj so that Avinash knows that you have responded - can you see the changes if you open up the LiveCD again? Also, please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question.

Comment: Apologies, but I am struggling with this forum. A bit foreign at the moment....

Comment: @AvinashRaj you could also read the partition table data here

Comment: which partition did you created from the above?

Comment: So Ext2 is my new partition (see edited question). I wanted to bring all my files over from my external drive, but I don't know how to access the partition. What application will access it. Apologies, but screen shots are a bit beyond my one hour's Ubuntu skill set...

Comment: Yes @wilf I can see the changes. I have installed Gparted in Ubuntu also, and when I run it my new partition is visible.

Comment: *The `sudo fdisk -l` output would be a bit more helpful...* Anyway, do you mean that you want to copy files to it and from it? You need to mount it - it either should appear in the side pane of the file browser (if it is not in the side pane in the default one (Nautilus), try [Dolphin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dolphin/) instead), and/or in `fdisk -l`. You should be able to mount it using `mount /dev/??? /PATH/OF/EMPTY/FILE/TO/MOUNT/IT/TO` - you can find the `???` in `fdisk`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create **ext4** partition,which was the successor of ext3 and ext2 filesystems.After creating ext4 partition,your ubuntu will detect it and automatically mounted it.There you can store all your datas.

OR

open gparted,note the ext2 filesystem label.It will be like `/dev/sdxx`.The xx denotes last two letters of your ext2 partition label.Then try the below command to manually mount it.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxx
```

Comment: ext2 is auto-detected though...

Comment: @avinash. Having a hard time trying to get my bios to recognise my usb pen. So I reboot, start liveUbuntu, run GParted again and delete my ext2 and create a new one called ext4?

Comment: now it worked or not.

Comment: @avinash in terminal I get:[sudo] password for chris: 
mount: /dev/sda3 already mounted or /media/0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9 busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda3 is already mounted on /media/0c997a25-85ee-4190-8d14-daef8e29dea9

Comment: Also in gparted when I right click on the new partition is offers an unmount option so I assume that it must already be mounted.

Comment: go to computer->uername->media->there you can find your partition.

Comment: ahh... :-) splendid. It's on the application bar. Thank you @Avinash.

Comment: Do I somehow mark this question as answered?

Comment: yes,please mark it.

Comment: @Avinash. If I right click the partition the option to create a new folder is greyed out?

Comment: go into the partition,then rightclick on it and select open in terminal.Now run this command `sudo mkdir folder-name`.

Comment: @Avinash don't I have to specify the partition?

Comment: @chris you got the solution.plz mark it as accepted and ask another question.

Comment: @Avinash. I would if I knew how. :-) But that's not a question.